# firebase function Puppeteer Could not find Chromium GCP

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have been using GCP for a long time with google cloud, and I wanted to run a cloud function that uses Puppeteer, but unfortunately, I am getting the following error.

---

Unhandled error Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1069273). This can occur if either

1. you did not install before running the script (e.g., `npm install`) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer).
   For (2), check out our guide on configuring Puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
   at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:120:27)
   at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
   at ChromeLauncher.launch (/workspace/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
   at async /workspace/lib/index.js:122:21
   at async /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:407:26

---

My code is

```
export const test = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 120,
    memory: "512MB" || "2GB",
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");

    browser.close();
    return { msg: "all good", status: 200 };
  });
```

I copy from [here](https://rominirani.com/using-puppeteer-in-google-cloud-functions-809a14856e14) an example of how to use Puppeteer in the GCP function (worked on my machine),
I also tried other functions that don't use Puppeteer, which work fine (so I am sure the problem is with Puppeteer).
I also tried to add the flag "--disable-setuid-sandbox"  but that didn't work.
I am writing the firebase function with Typescript.
My package.json has the following settings.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.21.0",
    "puppeteer": "^19.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/puppeteer": "^7.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "private": true
```

My tsconfig.json file has the following setting.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src",
    "node_modules/@types/puppeteer/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I also have in the lib directory the .puppeteerrc.cjs file according to [here](https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration/).

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

I tried adding it next to index.js, index.ts,package.json, firebase.json, but that did not change it.
I tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules.
I tried to follow StackOverflow questions.
[Deploying firebase function with Puppeteer says chrome can't be found even thoough I have enabled --no-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74089894/deploying-firebase-function-with-puppeteer-says-chrome-cant-be-found-even-thoou)

[Not able to migrate firebase functions to node 10 runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756506/not-able-to-migrate-firebase-functions-to-node-10-runtime)

[puppeteer-in-firebase-functions-failed-to-launch-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569113/puppeteer-in-firebase-functions-failed-to-launch-chrome)

Answer (score 7):

downgrading puppeteer helped:

```
npm remove puppeteer
npm install puppeteer@16.2.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: Still have the same error... I dockerized it and shipped it as a node server but could not make it work with the cloud function.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue. The simplest fix that I could find was to downgrade to Puppeteer 16.2.0 version. It is a deprecated version of Puppeteer but it should work.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with puppeteer ^19.8.0 on cloud-functions. The issue was the build layer used when deploying cloud functions contains the chromium binaries already. A simple `node_modules/puppeteer/install.js` said it already found in the build log. cloud-functions use a different base container image for runtime. The trick was the set the cache directory inside the application source directory. Using `puppeteer.config.js` file in the root and the sample from the docs:

```
const { join } = require("path");

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, ".cache", "puppeteer"),
};
```

GCP cloud-functions copies the source code directory to the runtime container allowing it to find the cache. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Add `"gcp-build": "node node_modules/puppeteer/install.mjs"` to the scripts and make sure that you have a `.puppeteerrc.cjs` at the root directory which includes the following

```
const {join} = require('path');
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer')
};
```

**** Note `install.mjs` not `install.js` *****

Comment: Do you have a doc pointing to ".mjs" rather than ".js"? I can confirm that for me, this adjustment in package.json allowed me to deploy my cloud functions to firebase with latest version of puppeteer 21.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation on how to bundle puppeteer.
https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration#examples

Create a new file in the root of the application, (usually the functions folder) named ".puppeteerrc.cjs".

Add the following configuration to it:

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

after adding the file you'll need to reinstall puppeteer.

```
npm remove puppeteer
npm i puppeteer
```

Add the new .cache folder to .gitignore.

Add the new .cache folder to firebase.json functions ignore.
open firebase.json, find the ignore array under functions, and add ".cache" to it.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is using Puppeteer ^21.6.0, I add a postinstall script to my package.json to install chrome. Along with puppeteerrc.js file that others have suggested.

```
"postinstall": "puppeteer browsers install chrome"
```

Somehow this results in the function having the browser available on every execution. I guess `npm install` gets called before execution, or something like that. It didn't work when I used a `gcp-build` script.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that finally work for me was to add this .puppeteerrc.cjs file in my functions folder :

> const {join} = require('path');
>
> module.exports =
> {   cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, 'node_modules',
> '.puppeteer_cache'), };

as explained at the Running Puppeteer on Google Cloud Functions section of this piece of documentation: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#running-puppeteer-on-google-cloud-functions